# Angular 8.3: How to prevent <a href> tag from default anchoring when jumping in a page instead of adding a dummy <a href> >?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, anchor, magnolia

Problem:
After building a page with a combination of magnolia-cms & angular, there appeared a problem. On the page, I had 2 link components(including `<a href>` tags) on the bottom. So, when the page opened, it always auto-scrolled with a mini delay on the bottom. If I removed one of them, still it happened due to the other.
I tried to include `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` (or `document.respective_element.scrollTop()`) in both of the 2 components, but it did not work, unless I included a timeout of around 500ms or more. Which, of course, was not a proper or satisfying solution.

Workaround-solution:
Added an `<a href>` tag in one of the top components(i.e. title), therefore, it auto-anchored there. So, no need for addition of `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` or similar.

Needed-solution/explanation:
Why is this happening and how to prevent it? For example, one thing I tried is that attribute
`autofocus="true"` caught the focus, but if `autofocus="false"`, it just auto-scrolled down. Wouldn't it be better just this default situation not to exist? Just to prevent it somehow?